# DateTime.TryParse changes the actual date value C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to handle the retrieved date value.

```
string dateValue = "2018-11-06T22:31:00.000Z";  // retrieved not assigned
DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, out convertedDate);
OnBoardingModel.reservedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(convertedDate.ToString()).ToString("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

the value of OnBoardingModel.reservedDate after DateTime.TryParse is Nov 7, 2018 04:01:00 AM . But Ideally it should be Nov 6(Line 1). Can I know how to parse the exact value? Thanks

Comment: Question: why do you do `Convert.ToDateTime(convertedDate.ToString())`? I suspect that's where the problem lies, so: what are you trying to do there? Note: I *suspect* that a lot of this relates to differences between UTC and local time.

Comment: remove the 'hh:mm:ss tt' from your ToString function

Comment: @Gerwin that wouldn't change the fact that the date is different...

Comment: `TryParse` doesn't change the value. `ToString()` and `ConvertToDateTime()` use the thread's current settings though which means at least one conversion to *local* time*.

Comment: that's true, but it is part of the issue, besides the reason that the date time returns a different date is because of the server / localhost timezone settings, @poornesh you should look into culture settings by default it'll be the culture of the location the server is located @ or the culture of your local machine you can read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2 for more information

Comment: 22:31 UTC is 04:01 *the next day* Indian time, which I'm going to hazard a wild guess is where you are. Think about time zones.

Comment: @AakashM aye, I was just looking up the list :) IST === UTC+05:30

Comment: @AakashM yeah I am in India..Is there a possibility where I can just have the date  similar to the one  that I have in the string.

Comment: @PoorneshV you need to either look at your server settings, or look at the culture settings, and change them so that the .toString() function just parses it, and doesn't convert it to your local (or servers) date time

Comment: @Gerwin Thank you.

Comment: When parsing, you need to tell your code NOT TO adjust to local time zone. You can achieve that by adding the `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` flag to your `TryParse` call. Will endup looking like this: `DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out var convertedDate);`. DateTime <=> string conversions have always been shady with the time zones issue and you really have to take caution with those ones.

Comment: DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out convertedDate);      works for me Thank you @gerryc.inc

Comment: Pleasure @PoorneshV. For future reference, have read about this library https://nodatime.org/ which tries to address these issues with DateTime. Depending on how complex your datetime requirements are, it might be a good alternative.